# Sending and receiving mail in java using mail transfer agent SendMail

Tags: java, netbeans-7, sendmail

I want to send and receive mail through my java program using SendMail which is a Mail Transfer Agent in linux....How to integrate the API's of SendMail in my java program so that I can use it for sending and receiving mail through my program....

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a specific API for sendmail - it speaks SMTP so you can just the [javamail api](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) to send your emails via your server.